# operational characteristics and working principle of finite automata

Tags: computation-theory

Discuss operational characteristics and working principle of finite automata with an example?

Can anybody give me hint on this? I am confused with term operational characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking you to describe the things that distinguish a finite state machine from other types of computational machines (e.g. Turing machines). What is interesting about a FSM and how does it work?